# Strange .Net Remoting Error

Tags: .net, serialization, remoting

This is driving me crazy ..
So i have a third Party lib, that uses log4net and some other dlls.
i added the library to my Project dependencies (with copy) and i had to implement Assembly.LoadFrom in order to get the library running. The dlls from within the direcorty of the external library are loaded correctly.

Now i get a very strange Serialization Exception, when i am calling a function via .Net Remoting of my own Services.

```
Unable to find assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bblaa2a'.

    Server stack trace: 
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap.Create(String name, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeBinaryResponseMessage(Stream inputStream, IMethodCallMessage reqMsg, Boolean bStrictBinding)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.DeserializeMessage(IMethodCallMessage mcm, ITransportHeaders headers, Stream stream)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at IMyRemoteServer.Ping()
       ...
       at xxxButtonClick()
       ...
```

Now i don't use log4net at all in IMyRemoteServer nor in any other Services. Also the Appdomain.AssemblyResolve (in the Client) is not called at all when calling the function. The log4net dll is present in the Directory of the third Party lib.

And what's even stranger, if i call the function a second time, it will not throw an error but work as expected...

Any hints what this could be?